# References in XML data with flixel + Actionscript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flixel

So I have this in an file which has been turned into a xml file. This file has an array in it, with a specific set up, like this:

```
<level morestuff>
    <Ground tileset = "Tiles" exportMode = "CSV">
         //info
    </Ground>
</level>
```

How would i got about getting

a) tileset

b) the info within the Ground tag

This is one of the first times I have used an XML file, so please excuse if this is a super simple question.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i figured it out, although it may not be the simplest or best method.

I imported the `flash.xml.*` and used the `elements()` function.

I used

```
xmlFileName.elements("Ground");
```

This got everything inside the `<Ground>` for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this :

```
var xml:XML = 
    <level>
        <Ground tileset = "Tiles" exportMode = "CSV">
             some data here
        </Ground>
    </level>
;
trace(xml.Ground);      // gives : some data here
```

OR, when you are loading data from an external file :

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(
        Event.COMPLETE, 
        function(e:Event):void {
            var xml:XML = new XML(loader.data);
            trace(xml.Ground);      // gives : some data here
        }
    )
    loader.load(new URLRequest('your_xml_file.xml'));
```

For more infos, you can take a look on [Working with XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html) from help.adobe.com.

Hope all that can help.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't worked much with this, I will definitely give it a try though.